# How to put conditions in tKinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have to apply an if else condition in a program. I am new to python GUI and not able to figure out how to put if else statements in my program.

if else statement is below:

```
if(weight>50 and glue==1):
    print("Tear in Seat")
elif(weight<50 and glue==0):
    print("No Tear in Seat")
elif(weight>70 and glue==0):
    print("Tear in Seat")
elif(weight<70 and glue==1):
    print("No tear in Seat")
```

Here is my GUI form:

```
from tkinter import *
fields = 'Weight Applied', 'Glue 0 || 1'

def fetch(entries, weight, glue):
for entry in entries:
    field = entry[0]
    text = entry[1].get()
    print('%s: "%s"' % (field, text))
if weight > 50 and glue == 1:
    print("Tear in Seat")
elif weight < 50 and glue == 0:
    print("No Tear in Seat")
elif weight > 70 and glue == 0:
    print("Tear in Seat")
elif weight < 70 and glue == 1:
    print("No tear in Seat")

def makeform(root, fields):
   entries = []
   for field in fields:
      row = Frame(root)
      lab = Label(row, width=15, text=field, anchor='w')
      ent = Entry(row)
      row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)
      lab.pack(side=LEFT)
      ent.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=YES, fill=X)
      entries.append((field, ent))
   return entries


if __name__ == '__main__':
   root = Tk()
   ents = makeform(root, fields)
   root.bind('<Return>', (lambda event, e=ents: fetch(e)))
   b1 = Button(root, text='Show', command=(lambda e=ents: fetch(e)))
   b1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
   b2 = Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit)
   b2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
   root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The if else block should be put inside `fetch()` function.

Comment: @acw1668 thanks for your response but do I have to make a new function for this as I am not sure how I put my if else block in that.

Comment: You can assign values to `weight` and `glue` inside for loop in `fetch()`.  Then add the if else block below the for loop.

Comment: @acw1668 I have updated my code and added if else block inside fetch(). As you said to pass values for `weight` and `glue` they are not constant values

Comment: Your changes will not be working as you do not pass `weight` and `glue` to `fetch()` in the two `lambda`s.  I have proposed the changes in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code logic, the `if-else` block should be put inside `fetch(...)` function as below:

```
def fetch(entries):
    weight = glue = 0
    for entry in entries:
        field = entry[0]
        text = entry[1].get()
        if 'Weight' in field:
            weight = int(text)
        elif 'Glue' in field:
            glue = int(text)
    print("weight:", weight, ", glue:", glue)
    if weight > 50 and glue == 1:
        print("Tear in Seat")
    elif weight < 50 and glue == 0:
        print("No Tear in Seat")
    elif weight > 70 and glue == 0:
        print("Tear in Seat")
    elif weight < 70 and glue == 1:
        print("No tear in Seat")
    else:
        print("Invalid weight and glue")
```